# Pandas read_sql - ignoring error if table does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I have a list of SQL scripts I have narrowed down and want to execute.  The data in the list follows this pattern more or less:

```
[DROP TABLE ABC ....;, CREATE TABLE ABC ....;, INSERT INTO TABLE ABC .....;,UPDATE TABLE ABC .....;]
```

Then it repeats itself for the next table.  All of this is confined to a single list below:

```
dfToList_P
```

The problem I am having is when a table doesn't exist, I want to ignore the error and execute the CREATE TABLE statement that follows it.  Here is my code:

```
def load_test_table(self):
    s = self.connection()
    df = self.retrieve_sql()
    df_P = df.loc[df['STEP_TYPE'] == 'P']
    dfToList_P = df_P['SQL_SCRIPT'].tolist()

    try:
        for sql_script in dfToList_P:
            #print(sql_script)
            pd.read_sql(sql_script, s)
    except teradata.DatabaseError as ex:
        sql_state = ex.args[0]
        if sql_state == 3807:
            print('Tried to DROP table that did not exist:' + sql_script)
        else:
            print('DatabaseError in SQL Script: ' + sql_script)
```

I google'd around and added the try/except condition but I don't think that is actually doing anything in this instance.

Running the script errors out with:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'DROP TABLE ABC;': (3807, "[42S02] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-3807)Object 'ABC' does not exist.")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont understand why are you dropping the table on `pd.read_sql()`. Why use pandas for this?

Comment: add a continue line in your exception. After the exception is met  the script doesn't know what to do next

Comment: @EdekiOkoh that won't work. The entire `for` loop fails. The exception handler should be _within_ the `for` loop

Comment: Also, I don't understand how trying to drop a table in the event that it _doesn't exist_ is logical.

Comment: @roganjosh  sorry if I wasn't clear, if the table doesn't exist I just want to move onto the Create Table statement. If the table DOES exist, I want the DROP statement to execute, and then the Create Table statement

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks to a combo of comments above.  First, my Try/Except was in the incorrect location and also I switched from using pandas read_sql to just using regular session execute and it worked as expected.  If table exists, drop it first, if not then create it.

Revised code below:

```
def load_test_table(self):
    s = self.connection()
    df = self.retrieve_sql()
    df_P = df.loc[df['STEP_TYPE'] == 'P']
    dfToList_P = df_P['SQL_SCRIPT'].tolist()

    for sql_script in dfToList_P:
        try:
            s.execute(sql_script)
        except teradata.DatabaseError as ex:
            sql_state = ex.args[0]
            if sql_state == 3807:
                print('Tried to DROP table that did not exist:' + sql_script)

            else:
                print('DatabaseError in SQL Script: ' + sql_script)
            continue
```